# Column values to a row in Db2 like xargs in Linux

Tags: sql, database, db2

I want to do the following in only SQL:

```
db2 -x "select colname from syscat.columns where tabschema like 'SYSCAT%' and tabname = 'TABLES' order by colno" | xargs
```

How can I do that? Convert the list of values into a row, like the xargs in Linux.
I want something dynamic, not with CASE, because I need to change the Tablename and  the result should be a row.

Original query:

```
col1
col2
col3
```

After xargs

```
col1 col2 col3
```

I know there is a function called ARRAY_AGG, but it only works inside a compound block, not a SQL query.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050494.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
SELECT TABNAME
,      LISTAGG(COLNAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLNO) AS COLNAMES
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA LIKE 'SYSCAT%'
GROUP BY TABNAME
ORDER BY TABNAME
```

it returns output such as this

```
 TABNAME                        COLNAMES
 ------------------------------ -----------------------------------
 BUFFERPOOLDBPARTITIONS         BUFFERPOOLID,DBPARTITIONNUM,NPAGES
 BUFFERPOOLEXCEPTIONS           BUFFERPOOLID,MEMBER,NPAGES
 BUFFERPOOLNODES                BUFFERPOOLID,NODENUM,NPAGES
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the LISTAGG function instead.

```
db2 -x "select listagg(colname, ' ') within group (order by colno) from syscat.columns where tabschema like 'SYSCAT%' and tabname = 'TABLES'" | xargs
```

Comment: Ok, that is the answer, but can you do something more elaborate.

Comment: I meant, modify the answer to give the whole solution in the answer, not in a comment. Thank you anyway